# Is there a way to detect when a row changed with a UL of float-lefted LIs?

Tags: css, javascript, jquery

Here's an example list I have of products: http://imgur.com/7IGthIa

I've got a function that runs on document-ready that cycles through each list and adjusts the height of a span around the img, so that the space is uniform throughout the entire list.

What I'm wondering is, is there a way to have it detect when the "row" changes, so that the spans appear as-is on the first row (as they're sized appropriately based on the first two, but on the second row, with the single entry, the span is the height of THAT image?

The function does the same thing with the height of the LI elements, and I'll probably adjust it to size this per row as well, if there's a workable solution.

This is the function it runs to calculate the height, if it's of any use:

```
if ( jQuery('.product_list').length ) {

    var tallest = 0;
    var tallest_img = 0;
    jQuery('.product_list li').each( function() {
        if ( jQuery(this).height() > tallest ) { tallest = jQuery(this).height(); }
        if ( jQuery(this).children('a').children('span').children('img').height() > tallest_img ) { 
            tallest_img = jQuery(this).children('a').children('span').children('img').height(); 
        }
    });
    jQuery('.product_list li').height( tallest );
    jQuery('.product_list li span').height( tallest_img );

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect when a row changes by checking an element's `offset().top`.

Since you're setting heights on the `span`s, I'll assume they have a style of `display: inline-block`.  (You can't set the height of an inline element.)

Since the `span`s are children of the `li`s, you shouldn't have to worry about setting the `li` heights (unless I misunderstood your question).

This code iterates through the `span`s, giving them equal heights per row based on the tallest `img` within each row:

```
function sizeSpans() {
  var spans= $('ul span'),
      tallest,
      top= $(spans[0]).offset().top;

  spans.css('height', '');
  tallest= $(spans[0]).height();

  spans.each(function(idx1) {
    if($(this).offset().top === top) {
      tallest= Math.max(tallest, $(this).height());
      spans.each(function(idx2) {
        if(idx2 <= idx1 && 
           $(this).offset().top === top
          ) {
          $(this).css('height', tallest);
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      tallest= $(this).height(),
      top= $(this).offset().top;
    }
  });
} //sizeSpans
```

You can add this to a `resize` handler:

```
$(window).resize(sizeSpans);
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hmhqs6gb/)

Click the **Size spans** button at top.  Resize the frame to see sizes readjust.